# Github Pages not detecting that repo name is my username

Tags: github-pages

I'm trying to set up a site with Github pages.

My Github username has a mix of capital and lowercase.

Every way I have tried naming the repo results in it publishing at "username.github.io/username" rather than "username.github.io".

[image: Repo name matching profile name]
[image: URL with subdomain]

Renaming the repo with all lowercase has the same result. Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is sumple: The domain needs to be included.

Name your repo `jrhutson.github.io` instead of `JRHutson`.

This will link your repository to the URL `https://jrhutson.github.io` and not `https://jrhutson.github.io/JRHutson`.

See https://pages.github.com/ (step 1) for reference.

Comment: Thank you. Should have looked at the documentation more carefully.